# Смена css кода по клику

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть вот такой код по клику на кнопку меняется фон и цвет текста body, как сделать что бы по клику той же кнопки менялись стили любого  элемента(тега, класса)

```js
var btn = document.getElementById('btn');

btn.onclick = function() {
  document.body.classList.toggle('change-mode');
}
```

```css
.change-mode {
  background: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<button id="btn">сменить режим</button>
<p>lorem ipsum dolor</p>
```

Comment: @МаксимЛенский я спросил в прошлом вопросе, сказали лучше создать новый вопрос на эту тему

Comment: А есть разница ?

Comment: @МаксимЛенский там был другой вопрос и на него ответили как надо, а здесь я спрашиваю немного другое

Comment: ну тогда - получается надо явно указать что вы хотите поменять - для примера есть некие контейнеры - у них по оформлению какие то стили - а вот при клике вы эти стили меняете а вот на какие стили меняете надо написать и так для всего что есть на странице , я покажу как я меняю стили универсально https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/pKVQPB?editors=0110

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял суть вопроса, то вот ответ.

И с тегами, и с классами, и с id.

```js
$('.btn').on('click', function(){
 $('div').toggleClass('change-mode');
  $('span').toggleClass('change-mode2');
  $('i').toggleClass('change-mode3');
  $('#four').toggleClass('change-mode4');
  $('.second').toggleClass('change-mode5');
});
```

```css
.change-mode {
  background: black;
  color: white;
}

.change-mode:hover{
  color: #aaa;
  background-color: #111;
}

.change-mode2 {
  background: yellow;
  color: red;
}

.change-mode2:hover{
  color: #bbb;
  background-color: #222;
}

.change-mode3 {
  background: pink;
  color: green;
}

.change-mode3:hover{
  color: #ccc;
  background-color: #333;
}

.change-mode4 {
  background: grey;
  color: orange;
}

.change-mode4:hover{
  color: #ddd;
  background-color: #444;
}

.change-mode5 {
  background: purple;
  color: brown;
}

.change-mode5:hover{
  color: #eee;
  background-color: #555;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div>
    <button class="btn">сменить режим</button>
    <span>lorem ipsum dolor</span>
  </div>
   <div>
    <p class='second'>lorem ipsum dolor</p>
  </div>
   <div>
    <i>lorem ipsum dolor</i>
  </div>
   <div>
    <p id='four'>lorem ipsum dolor</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Как сделать что бы hover эффект тоже менялся, можно ли так вообще ?

Comment: @DawdM  у вас же там нету hover

Comment: В данном примере нету, это не тестовый код, а вообще возможно ? Если да то как?

Comment: @DawdM ну если примерно то так : по клику на кнопку добавляем body любой class а в css пишем что `body.new button:hover {background:blue;}` это примерно для более точного ответа надо видеть реальный пример

Comment: @DawdM  вот так - я добавляю hover эффект в теме dark а в других темах нету: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/pKVQPB

Comment: Для input не применяется стиль

Comment: почему hover меняет только background а цвет текста не меняет

Answer (score 0):

По первому вопросу - мы можем так менять тему - с боку три кнопки 
В теме dark есть второй клик в котором мы дважды меняем hover

```js
$(".linear").on("click", function() {
  $("body").css({
    "background": "linear-gradient(45deg, lightblue,green,#fff)"
  });
  $("body").removeClass("new new1");
});
$(".dark").on("click", function() {
  $("body").addClass("new").css({
    "background": "#202020",
    "filter": "invert(50)"
  });
});

$(".dark").on("dblclick", function() {
  $("body").addClass("new1").css({
    "background": "#202020",
    "filter": "invert(50)"
  });
});

$(".light").on("click", function() {
  $("body").css({
    "background": "#fff",
    "filter": "invert(0)"
  });
  $("body").removeClass("new new1");
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
}

main {
  padding: 20px;
}

main div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: row;
}

main h2 {
  padding: 20px 0;
}

main div p {
  padding: 0 30px;
}

.colorsheme {
  position: fixed;
  top: 14px;
  right: 10px;
}

.colorsheme span {
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #000;
}

.new {
  filter: invert(50)!important;
}

.new span:hover {
  background: violet;
}

.new1 {
  filter: invert(50)!important;
}

.new1 span:hover {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="colorsheme">
  <span class="linear">linear</span>
  <span class="dark">dark</span>
  <span class="light">light</span>
</div>
<main>
  <h2>Какой то заголовок</h2>
  <div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200/cc0" alt="">
    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente, nemo modi laborum tempora quam impedit distinctio autem nesciunt placeat ipsum praesentium est corrupti! Ut nobis eveniet voluptates quod eaque alias! </p>
  </div>
</main>

<main>
  <h2>Какой то заголовок</h2>
  <div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200/cc0" alt="">
    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente, nemo modi laborum tempora quam impedit distinctio autem nesciunt placeat ipsum praesentium est corrupti! Ut nobis eveniet voluptates quod eaque alias! </p>
  </div>
</main>
```